# How to get the current object / product from the class based detail view in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-class-based-views

```
'''Models Code'''
# Product Model
class Products(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='productImage')
    CATEGORY = (
        ('Snacks','Snacks'),
        ('Juice','Juice'),
    )
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=CATEGORY)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.FloatField()
# Rating Model
class Rating(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Products, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stars = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1),MaxValueValidator(5)], blank=True, null=True)
    comment = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)

''' Views Code '''

class ProductListView(ListView):
    model = Products
    template_name = 'products.html'
    context_object_name ='Products'


class ProductDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin,DetailView):
    login_url = '/accounts/login'
    model = Products

# Using this function I want to take the rating and comment, but how can I access the cuurent object for which the comment and rating is being send by the user.
def review(request,slug):
    star=request.POST.get('rating')
    comment=request.POST.get('comment')
    user = request.user
    productId = request.POST.get('productsid') # How to get the Product
    product = Products.objects.get(id=productId)
    review = Rating(product=product,user=user,stars=star,comment=comment)
    review.save()
    return redirect('/')

# Urls code
urlpatterns = [
  path('',views.home,name='Home'),
  path('products',ProductListView.as_view(),name='Products'),
  path('product/<int:pk>',ProductDetailView.as_view(),name='Product-Details'),
  path('contact',views.contact,name='Contact'),
  path('review',views.review,name='review')

#Templates Code
<form method="POST" action="review">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="hidden" id="rating-value" name="rating">
<textarea  style="margin-top:5px;" class="form-control" rows="3" id="comment" placeholder="Enter your review" name="comment"></textarea>
<button type="submit" style="margin-top:10px;margin-left:5px;" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>
```

How to fetch the current object from the deatailed view page in the review function?
I have added the code here. In Product detailed view page it is rendering the page through which I want to take rating and comment for the product . Is there any other way through which I can get the product, user , star, and rating field value and store it in the data base?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can point out some ways to retrieve the `product_id` in your `review` function.

**First approach:**

You can pass the `product_id` as a URL parameter. In this case, I hope the `review` view is called from the product detail page.

So, your url should be something like:

```
path('review/<int:product_id>', views.review, name="review),
```

Your view:

```
def review(request, *args, **kwargs):
    star=request.POST.get('rating')
    comment=request.POST.get('comment')
    user = request.user
    productId = kwargs.get('product_id') # change is here
    product = Products.objects.get(id=productId)
    review = Rating(product=product,user=user,stars=star,comment=comment)
    review.save()
    return redirect('/')
```

Your template:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'review' object.pk %}">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="hidden" id="rating-value" name="rating">
<textarea  style="margin-top:5px;" class="form-control" rows="3" id="comment" placeholder="Enter your review" name="comment"></textarea>
<button type="submit" style="margin-top:10px;margin-left:5px;" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>
```

In the template, the `object` is the object_name you have given to the product object. You can change the object name by adding:

```
context_object_name = product
```

in your `ProductDetailView`.

**Second approach:**

Pass the product_id as a form data. You can create a hidden input in your template that will contain the product_id as value. For example:

In your template:

```
<form method="POST" action="review">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="hidden" id="rating-value" name="rating">
<input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="{{ object.pk }}"> # add a hidden input field
<textarea  style="margin-top:5px;" class="form-control" rows="3" id="comment" placeholder="Enter your review" name="comment"></textarea>
<button type="submit" style="margin-top:10px;margin-left:5px;" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Where `object` is what I mentioned previously.

Then you can retrieve the product_id in view as:

```
def review(request,slug):
    star=request.POST.get('rating')
    comment=request.POST.get('comment')
    user = request.user
    productId = int(request.POST.get('product_id')) # here
    product = Products.objects.get(id=productId)
    review = Rating(product=product,user=user,stars=star,comment=comment)
    review.save()
    return redirect('/')
```